# Finding an interval containing the values of $ abc(a + b + c) $, given a quadratic constraint

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $ a, b, c $ are real numbers such that $$ (ab)^2 + (bc)^2 + (ca)^2 = k $$
then all possible values of $ abc(a + b + c) $ lies between which interval?

Comment: Please edit the title of your problem.

Comment: You should specify if you want a minimal interval, or just any interval with that property. The interval $(-\infty,+\infty)$ clearly works...

Comment: Expand: $(ab + bc + ca)^2$

Answer (score 2):

Note $$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge xy+yz+zx$$

then we have
$$k=(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ac)^2\ge abc(a+b+c)$$
 other hand 
$$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+xz)\ge 0$$
so
$$xy+yz+xz\ge -\dfrac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$
so
$$abc(a+b+c)\ge -\dfrac{1}{2}[(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ac)^2]=-\dfrac{k}{2}$$
so
$$abc(a+b+c)\in [-\dfrac{k}{2},k]$$